# java fb2 library

Tags: java, api, frameworks, fb2

I want api for creating fb2 files. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is apparently an [XML schema](http://www.fictionbook.org/index.php/Eng%3aXML_Schema_Fictionbook_2.1) against which you can validate your files.  They would probably be created just like any other XML files.